# Laravel query builder doesn't work with COALESCE

Tags: laravel, builder

This MySQL query works perfectly and return values in both `subject` and `body_html` columns.

```sql
SELECT
    translations.id,
    COALESCE(locale.subject, fallback.subject) as subject,
    COALESCE(locale.body_html, fallback.body_html) as body_html 
FROM
    translations
LEFT JOIN
    translations AS locale
    ON locale.translatable_id = translations.translatable_id
    AND locale.translatable_type = translations.translatable_type
    AND locale.locale = "fr" 
LEFT JOIN
    translations AS fallback
    ON fallback.translatable_id = translations.translatable_id
    AND fallback.translatable_type = translations.translatable_type
    AND fallback.locale = "en" 
WHERE
    translations.translatable_id = 1
    AND translations.translatable_type = "App\\Models\\Email" 
LIMIT 1;
```

Now the same with the Laravel query builder, (note: the variables used here have a correct value):

```php
return Translation::selectRaw(
        'translations.id,'.
        'COALESCE(locale.subject, fallback.subject) AS subject,'.
        'COALESCE(locale.body_html, fallback.body_html) AS body_html'
    )
    ->where('translations.translatable_id', $this->id)
    ->where('translations.translatable_type', get_class($this))
    ->leftJoin('translations AS locale', function ($join) use($locale) { 
        $join->on('locale.translatable_id', 'translations.translatable_id')
            ->where('locale.translatable_type', 'translations.translatable_type')
            ->where('locale.locale', $locale);
    })
    ->leftJoin('translations AS fallback', function ($join) {
        $join->on('fallback.translatable_id', 'translations.translatable_id')
            ->where('fallback.translatable_type', 'translations.translatable_type')
            ->where('fallback.locale', config('app.fallback_locale'));
    })
    ->first();
```

The id column value is correct but `subject`and `body_html` column values are empty.
Why ?

Comment: Try installing something like Laravel Debugbar or Clockwork to check out the actual run SQL query. That may give you an indication. And if not append the found query to your answer which could help.

Comment: You can use the toSql function to see the query that is generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is mostly correct, but there's a mistake in both of your joins:

```php
->leftJoin('translations AS locale', function ($join) use($locale) { 
    $join->on('locale.translatable_id', 'translations.translatable_id')
        ->where('locale.translatable_type', 'translations.translatable_type') // <- HERE
        ->where('locale.locale', $locale);
})
```

```php
->leftJoin('translations AS fallback', function ($join) {
    $join->on('fallback.translatable_id', 'translations.translatable_id')
        ->where('fallback.translatable_type', 'translations.translatable_type') // <- HERE
        ->where('fallback.locale', config('app.fallback_locale'));
})
```

When you do `where('fallback.translatable_type', 'translations.translatable_type')`, it's not comparing the 2 columns.  It's trying to match `fallback.translatable_type` to the string literal `'translations.translatable_type'`.

Simply replace those `where` methods by either `whereColumn` or `on` and it should work.

```php
DB::table('translations')->selectRaw(
        'translations.id,'.
        'COALESCE(locale.subject, fallback.subject) AS subject,'.
        'COALESCE(locale.body_html, fallback.body_html) AS body_html'
    )
    ->where('translations.translatable_id', 1)
    ->where('translations.translatable_type', 'App\\Models\\Translation')
    ->leftJoin('translations AS locale', function ($join) { 
        $join->on('locale.translatable_id', 'translations.translatable_id')
            ->whereColumn('locale.translatable_type', 'translations.translatable_type')
            ->where('locale.locale', 'fr');
    })
    ->leftJoin('translations AS fallback', function ($join) {
        $join->on('fallback.translatable_id', 'translations.translatable_id')
            ->whereColumn('fallback.translatable_type', 'translations.translatable_type')
            ->where('fallback.locale', config('app.fallback_locale'));
    })
    ->first();
```

```php
DB::table('translations')->selectRaw(
        'translations.id,'.
        'COALESCE(locale.subject, fallback.subject) AS subject,'.
        'COALESCE(locale.body_html, fallback.body_html) AS body_html'
    )
    ->where('translations.translatable_id', 1)
    ->where('translations.translatable_type', 'App\\Models\\Translation')
    ->leftJoin('translations AS locale', function ($join) { 
        $join->on('locale.translatable_id', 'translations.translatable_id')
            ->on('locale.translatable_type', 'translations.translatable_type')
            ->where('locale.locale', 'fr');
    })
    ->leftJoin('translations AS fallback', function ($join) {
        $join->on('fallback.translatable_id', 'translations.translatable_id')
            ->on('fallback.translatable_type', 'translations.translatable_type')
            ->where('fallback.locale', config('app.fallback_locale'));
    })
    ->first();
```

Comment: That was it, `whereColumn` or `on` instead of `where`. Thanks for your help.